# Flexbox align-self and margin auto

Tags: css, flexbox, margin, vertical-alignment

What does this mean in align-self?

> If a flexbox item's cross-axis margin is auto, then align-self is
> ignored.

This is in Mozilla, **almost in the beginning:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self

**If you give me an example** it would be great thanks, I can't appreciate it without an example, the explanation is very vague.

```
<section>
  <div>Item #1</div>
  <div>Item #2</div>
  <div>Item #3</div>
</section>


div {
  height: 60px;
  background: cyan;
  margin: 5px;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Comment: Hi,I have updated the question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self

Comment: Set `margin-top: auto` for `.example-container>div` in the example on that page (via your browser dev tools), and see what change that brings when you switch between different `align-self` values now.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe, I noticed that it ignores it, so can we align flex elements (childs) also with automatic margins and that's why align-self is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You can align flex elements (childs) also with automatic margins:

Visit https://www.samanthaming.com/flexbox30/31-flexbox-with-auto-margins/

Visit https://hackernoon.com/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6

Visit https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I didn't know this way of aligning flex items existed.